# backbone JS refactoring inline collection out of view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm new to backbone.js and have inherited some code with a collection defined inside a method within a view.  I would like to pull it out into its own module but am struggling.  Here is the collection:

```
        ResourceCollection = AbstractCollection.extend({
            url: url,
            model: ResourceModel,
            state: state,
            queryParams: BackgridUtils.getQueryParams({
                _queryFilter: 'true'
            }, this.data.isSystemResource)
        });
        this.model.resources = new ResourceCollection();
```

And here is what the refactored module looks like so far:

```
define("resource/ResourceCollection", [
"underscore",
"main/AbstractCollection",
"util/BackgridUtils"
], function(_, AbstractCollection, BackgridUtils) {
    var ResourceCollection = AbstractCollection.extend({
        url: url,
        model: ResourceModel,
        state: state,
        queryParams: BackgridUtils.getQueryParams({
            _queryFilter: 'true'
        }, this.data.isSystemResource)
    });
    return new ResourceCollection;
});
```

How can I instantiate the collection from my view with the proper values?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should return the actual constructor of the collection rather than just an instance of it.
Then you can use this "module" to create instances of this collection anywhere else in your application.

```js
define("resource/ResourceCollection", [
  "underscore",
  "main/AbstractCollection",
  "util/BackgridUtils"
], function(_, AbstractCollection, BackgridUtils) {
  var ResourceCollection = AbstractCollection.extend({
    url: url,
    model: ResourceModel,
    initialize: function(models,options){
       //handle custome options here
    },
    state: state,
    queryParams: BackgridUtils.getQueryParams({
      _queryFilter: 'true'
    }, this.data.isSystemResource)
  });
  return ResourceCollection;
});
```

Then from your view you can create instances of your collection with dynamic data like

```
new ResourceCollection([],{
 url: "some dynamic url"
 //some other custom options can be passed here
})
```